log4net library outputs the log message location as the library code, not the calling code
My log4net library does one thing incorrectly. It outputs the file name and line of the library cs code where the log4net::Info method is invoked.
How can I setup this up to output the filename and number of the executable that's using the library?
My config file is complied into the library as an embedded resource. Here it is:
<log4net>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %file:%line - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>

My library class:
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LogLib
{
    public class Log4Net
   {
      public ILog logger;


      public void DeclareClass(System.Type className) { logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(className); }
      public Log4Net()
      {

      }

      public void Configure(string logFileName)
      {
         //string workingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
         //DirectoryInfo parentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory);
         //string logFilePath = parentDirectory.FullName + string.Format(@"\log\{0}.log", logFileName);

         // Construct the path to the log4net configuration file
         // Get the assembly where the Logger class is defined
         Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

         // Load the embedded log4net configuration file as a stream
         using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LogLib.log4net.config"))
         {
            // Check if the stream is valid
            if (stream != null)
            {
               // Configure log4net with the embedded configuration file
               XmlConfigurator.Configure(stream);
            }
            else
            {
               // Log an error if the embedded configuration file is not found
               logger.Error("Embedded log4net.config file not found.");
            }
         }

         // Set the log file name dynamically
         Assembly ass = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
         var repository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
         var appender = (log4net.Appender.FileAppender)repository.GetAppenders().First(a => a is log4net.Appender.FileAppender);
         appender.File = logFileName;
         appender.ActivateOptions();
      }

      public void LogInfo(string message)
      {
         logger.Info(message);
      }
   }
}

my console application:
using LogLib;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Log4Net lfn = new Log4Net();
         System.Type className = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
         lfn.DeclareClass(className);
         lfn.Configure("test.log");
         lfn.LogInfo("does this work?");
      }
   }
}

And the output:
2024-04-29 15:53:31,066 [10] INFO  ConsoleApplication5.Program c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\LogLib\Class1.cs:59 - does this work?

